# Is there a way to store a file in a React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project where I need to store an image in my components state, so that I can send the file and accompanying data to a different component that uploads the data to my Firebase Database and the image to my Firestore.

I've tried doing it by setting the state the normal way, using a functions that is called when an image is submitted. But the state in which I want to pass on the file remains empty.

The initial state:

```
state = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    date: '',
    ticket: '',
    price: '',
    image: []
}
```

The input:

```
<input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" onChange={this.handleChangeImage} />
```

The function that is supposed to handle my problem:

```
handleChangeImage = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: file
    });
}
```

If I console log the variable "file" I get the file, but console logging state.image will just show me an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is now resolved. I am an idiot. My problem wasn't that the state wasn't updated with the file, the problem was that the console log output happened before the state was updated with the file.

The state was always updated with the file, I just never realised.

The issue was in other words not an issue, just a plain dumb rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your handle function to this:

```
handleChangeImage = (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const newImages = [...this.state.image];
  newImages.push(file);
  this.setState({
    image: newImages
  });
}
```

Comment: `const newImages = this.state.image;` is only making a new pointer to the same array. You're thinking of `const newImages = [...this.state.image];`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this didn’t work either. The state remains empty of the file. I’m trying to look up if it’s even possible. But I can’t find any info on it.